# How to deploy only a single angular project in a multi-projects workspace

Tags: angular

i have an angular workspace which contains multi-projects , let say :

- Project-1
- Project-2

i have a requirement where the first project (Project-1) need to be changed and then deployed to production server without touching and deploying the second project (Project-2), i.e: i need to take Project-1 files generated from the build and deploy to production (replacing Project-1 only files).

Comment: Yes it’s possible. Not clear what is preventing you from doing it.

Comment: i already did the multi-projects , but what i want is to generate chunk js file(s) for projects-1 when needed and just go to my production server and replace the old chunk with the new generated one. i used :
loadChildren: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "projects-1" */ 'projects/project-1/src/app/app.module').then(m=>m.Project1SharedModule)

then i run : ng build --project=project-1 --prod
but :
(1) the name of the generated JS is random name and i am not able to change it
(2) when i take this JS to the root (workspace) and replace the old file with this new one then the application

Comment: You are supposed to deploy all generated files as is . Every project has dedicated output folder so it’s not clear what’s the problem. Simply remove old files and deploy new ones.

Comment: i am trying to do a multi-projects in a root workspace , same as the following article:
https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527

Answer (score 0):

You can build that project separately

```
ng build [ProjectName]
```

Comment: ng build [ProjectName] will generate output files in a separate folder (dist\Project-1) and this folder cannot be combined/merged in the root out folder (dist). 
what i am looking for is to configure the root (workspace) and the sub-projects so when i have a requirement to change sub-project only (ex: Project-1) i can build and take the output files and replace Project-1 files on production directly without the need to build whole projects (workspace).  I hope its clear :)

Comment: From Angular perspective there’s no “root” projects. All projects are equal and one of them is default. You are not supposed to have “root “ output folder

Comment: i am trying to do a multi-projects in a root workspace , same as the following article:
https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527

Comment: From what I see that article gives wrong impression of what’s going on. He does not create a root app but rather creates a new one and refers other “apps” like you would refer “libraries”. This has little sense. If you want libraries use libraries.